# How to read firestore documents array in a list with provider?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: firestore database screenshot]

Above image is the screenshot of the firestore database which I want to read on the order screen. But unable to do so. I want to display the **array** `orders` as a list of products on the order screen. Tried plenty of articles but unable to get the expected.

model_order.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Order with ChangeNotifier {
  final String userId;
  final String orderId;
  final String name;
  int phoneNumber;
  final String addressType;
  final String address;
  final String area;
  final String city;
  final String deliverySlot;
  final Timestamp createdAt;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> orders;


  Order({
    required this.userId,
    required this.orderId,
    required this.name,
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.addressType,
    required this.address,
    required this.area,
    required this.city,
    required this.deliverySlot,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.orders,
  });
}

class OrderProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Order> _orders = [];

  List<Order> get getOrders => _orders;

  Future<void> fetchOrders() async {

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('orders')
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot productSnapshot) {
      for (var element in productSnapshot.docs) {
        _orders.insert(
          0,
          Order(
            userId: element.get('userId'),
            orderId: element.get('orderId'),
            name: element.get('name'),
            phoneNumber: int.parse(element.get('phoneNumber').toString()),
            addressType: element.get('addressType'),
            address: element.get('address'),
            area: element.get('area'),
            city: element.get('city'),
            deliverySlot: element.get('deliverySlot'),
            createdAt: element.get('createdAt'),
            orders: element.get(FieldPath(['orders', 'title'])),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

// Order getById(String prodId) {
//   // return _orders.firstWhere((element) => element.id == prodId);
// }
}
```

order_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../models_providers/order.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class FullOrder extends StatefulWidget {
  const FullOrder({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FullOrderState createState() => _FullOrderState();
}

class _FullOrderState extends State<FullOrder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final order = Provider.of<Order>(context);
    final orderProvider = Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context);
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Order Id: ${order.orderId}'),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                    'Order Date: ${DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(order.createdAt.toDate())}'),
                Text(
                    'Order Time: ${DateFormat('kk:mm').format(order.createdAt.toDate())}'),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Customer Name',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(order.name),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Contact',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text('${order.phoneNumber}'),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Delivery Slot',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(order.deliverySlot),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Address',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text('${order.addressType},${order.address}'),
                    Text(order.area),
                    Text(order.city),
                  ],
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: order.orders.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(order.orders[index]['title']),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the line you're having issues with? (orders: element.get(FieldPath(['orders', 'title'])),) how to extract the **orders** field from the Firebase document?

Comment: Yes having problem in the FieldPath line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling the **orders** out of an array field from a document should be no different than reading another value, with the exception that this is a List as opposed to a simpler structure or primitive value type. I created this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/a4299ce88d233658c8a23042e4fb1c8e) for you to see how it works (run it through Dartpad.dev and check it out), but basically is pretty much pulling the value out of the document and casting it as a **List**, then each value in turn you can map it as a **Map<String, dynamic>**, as shown below (shown inside a **ListView.builder**):

```dart
FutureBuilder(
        // in my case I'm pulling all the documents in the "orders" collection
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders').get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            
            
            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> docs = (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                
                // this is each individual document Map
                var data = docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                // now this is the "orders" array inside the document
                var dataOrders = data['orders'] as List<dynamic>;

                // then each individual object in the array is mapped in turn as another Map
                var mappedDataOrders = dataOrders.map((o) => (o as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();
                
                // then do whatever you want with it
                return Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(data['orderId'].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      ...List.generate(
                        mappedDataOrders.length,
                        (index) {
                          var order = mappedDataOrders[index] as Map<String, dynamic>;
                          
                          return Text(order['title']);
                        }
                      )
                    ]
                  )
                );
              }
            )
```

Eventually you will have to map the **orders** array items the same way you are mapping the order documents (i noticed you have a List<Map<String, dynamic>> orders;) so you should map those into strongly-typed models (you could call them SubOrders or whatever you want).

This is how I replicated your Firebase on my end:

[image]

And this is how it looks when I run the Gist I gave you on DartPad:

[image]

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Roman Jaquez this helped in populating the list with array. It was running good in dart pad, but adding ```shrinkWrap: true,``` in ```ListView.builder``` helped me in achieving the list on editor.

Comment: One more thing I want to addon, populated list is duplicating the data at every refesh.